# Stackwise application for Ipad

Tags: support

I don't know if this site is the appropriate place but my question is this one:

The stackwise application for Ipad lets me visit all my favorite stackexchange sites. However, it doesn't seem to run latex and equations are seen as a bunch of code. I don't know latex yet. Has anyone had similar problems, or know how to solve this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The [Stackwise App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackwise/id556308691?ls=1&mt=8) appears to be third-party -- you should file a bug report with its developer.

On the other hand, the Stack Exchange team is [alpha-testing its official iPad app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239250/help-us-test-the-new-stack-exchange-ipad-app), and you can sign up to participate. My very limited understanding is that this is just a superficial change to the already-existing iOS app for optimal display on an iPad. Since the iOS app already displays latex properly ([I requested it myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222868/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-ios-app)), I suspect it won't be an issue there.

For future reference, bug reports and feature requests for official apps at least should probably go to the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and tagged appropriately. Even for latex it's not like Physics is the only Stack Exchange site that uses it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know this "already-existing iOS app for optimal display". Could you please tell me what you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @David iPads naturally run most apps written for iPhones, since they both use iOS. Since the iPhone app is already released, you could just use that. But the developers are aware that certain design elements should change between phones and tablets, so they're working on customizing the app to look better on tablets right now.